# How to print from XSJS to Console

Tags: hana, hana-xs

I have some code in XSJS to populate/Update my Hana DB based on some conditions. I am looking for a mechanism where I can print few comments to console or to some log file.

I know i can use console.log(); for normal javascript on web browser but it does not work on XSJS. Some other implementation of Server Side JS like node.js gives echo command. Is there something similar for XSJS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to log it temporarily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use $.trace.debug("Type your log comments here"); within the xsjs file and then you can see the logs in trace file under the 'Diagnosis File' section for system.

Before that you need to change the 'Database Trace' configuration for XS-Engine under the 'Trace Configuration' Section.

Comment: yeah figured that out .. thanks for your reply though ! Answer here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3527125